# UIPageViewController page segues to another scene which doesnt handle rotation

Tags: ios, ios6, modal-dialog, viewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I am building an app using UIPageViewController with the scrolling style do implement many pages that the user can swipe between, on each page they can click on a button that modally opens another scene with extra info but on this scene the rotation doesnt work, it looks like screen is trying to do something to re-position the elements but then they end up pointing sideways (e.g. same orientation as portrait mode). If I segue straight fromt the parent root controler to this scene then it works fine, but I need info from the page to include in the scene, so thats why Im trying to segue from the page.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I accidently deleted a statement:

```
[self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
```

This was in the original generated code and somehow I must have removed it. Now its added back the display works ok. Its funny that the issue did not affect the scrolling of the child pages but the modal scene